# Up Navigation vs onBackPressed() android - update Fragments with View Pager?

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is a test mode app, to test the device this application is installed on (display, key press, etc).

The application runs mainly on **one activity** with a **View Pager**, with several fragments simulating different "screens." Each of these fragments hosts a single button that then takes the user to another activity, through which they can test their device.

For example, pressing "Start Display Test" on the display **fragment** takes the user to a display **activity** where they are then presented with three images in a row; then this activity calls a global flag from MainActivity called DISPLAY_TEST_PASSED and sets it to true, and the user is navigated back to MainActivity with the **ViewPager** and the display **fragment**.

What I want to happen is for the text on the display **fragment** to update from "Display  Test" to "Display Test - Passed" ... but having the display **activity** call onBackPressed() after updating the flag doesn't update the text in the display **fragment**.

Interestingly enough, calling NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(DisplayTestActivity.this) from the display **activity** does in fact update the text in the display **fragment**. What's the difference? I though navigating up was the same as calling onBackPressed()?

A visual of my application:

```
    MainActivity (with view pager) : fragment1 ... DisplayFragment ... fragment3 ... fragment4 ...
                                                        |
                                                   DisplayActivity

    I want DisplayActivity to update MainActivity (and thus the display fragment)
    but for some reason this doesn't happen onBackPress() while it does on Up 
    Navigation. Why?
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a job for

`protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities